# who's headlining at Dreamforce '17

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

For the past gazillion years, customers, admins and user group members look for one good reason for attending Dreamforce, like there's just one, however, I find myself including that year's headline band as one of the good reason's to attend!

So I now need to know who is headlining the music at Dreamforce this year (2017)!

Solid answers only please!

Comment: Post for meta maybe?

Comment: didn't even think of that, i'll move it

Comment: ... or you could move it for me, thx!

Comment: I will be there this year . @Bartley Good to see you here :)